# need Help: Conceptual understanding of Navigation stack

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I have already used navigation stack on the robot. However, I still don't understand how it works.
Is there any research papers, or webpage (besides ros website that talks about global planner, local planner, move_base) that will explain how the navigation stack work, in general?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72952/need-help:-conceptual-understanding-of-navigation-stack/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd say the ROS website is probably the best documentation there is (at least it should be).

If you have some specific question about what is unclear, this would be the place to ask.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-08-15**:
ok. thank you for your reply dornhege!  I have two more questions:

1. do you think if we could run the robot in gazebo simulator AND in the real world at the SAME time?
2. is there any guidance (or a template) for writing the local planner in the navigation stack

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-08-15**:\

1. The question is: What should that do? What do you want to achieve? Essentially from the ROS perspective it will look like two robots. 2) The template is the interface to derive from. It's actually pretty clear. For examples look at TrajectoryPlannerROS or PoseFollower.